# win32 PostMessage WM_APPCOMMAND sends multiple messages instead of one

Tags: winapi, pinvoke, keyboard-events

I'm writing a small accessibility app which simulates certain keyboard gestures, such as volume up\down.

The goal is to send a single command.

In practice, the volume goes all the way up to 100%, as if user pressed a button for couple seconds or as if the message was dispatched multiple times.

This behavior is the same with both `PostMessage` and `SendMessage`, in both C and C# (using PInvoke)

C:

```
PostMessage(0xffff, 0x0319, 0, 0xa0000)
```

C#:

```
PostMessage(new IntPtr(0xffff), WindowMessage.WM_APPCOMMAND, (void*)0, (void*)0xa0000);
```

The meaning of parameters: *send to all windows, message, no source, volume up*

Question: **How do I issue a command which would result in Windows adjusting volume by the smallest increment?**

---

Additionally, I attempted using WP_KEYUP and WP_KEYDOWN, without success

```
// dispatch to all apps, message, wparam: virtual key, lparam: repeat count = 1
User32.PostMessage(new IntPtr(0xffff), User32.WindowMessage.WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(0xaf000), new IntPtr(1)); 
User32.PostMessage(new IntPtr(0xffff), User32.WindowMessage.WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(0xaf000), new IntPtr(1));
```

Comment: "Send to all windows" is a bad idea.  They'll each try to raise the volume, ending up with 100% is pretty much guaranteed.  One window is enough.  If you don't have your own then use GetDesktopWindow().

Comment: Or perhaps the focused window.

Comment: Thank you! Both `GetShellWindow()` and `GetForegroundWindow()` worked

Comment: Unless you are planning, that no-one will ever read this code, use symbolic constants in place of magic numbers. `HWND_BROADCAST` is readily available. Likewise, [WM_APPCOMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-appcommand) carries more meaning than `0x0319`. The same goes for the arguments: `APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP` (plus bitshifting) is way more meaningful than `0xa0000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the command is sent multiple times is, as pointed by Hans in the comment, I broadcasted it to all windows using `0xffff` as first parameter. Every window handled it by increasing volume by a notch.

The solution to sending multiple messages is to send the message to either

1. The shell handle `GetShellWindow()`
2. The foreground window handle `GetForegroundWindow()`

Both handles adjusted the volume by one notch. `GetDesktopWindow()` did not work, though.